# Postgres Number of Updates/Deletes Since Last Autovacuum

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

Is there a good way to monitor the number of updates/deletes to a table since the last autovacuum? I'm trying to find tables that aren't updated frequently enough to avoid `autovacuum (to prevent wraparound)`.

I was thinking of using `n_dead_tup` from `pg_stat_all_tables`, but is this a good idea/is there a better way?

I'm using Postgres 9.6.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n_dead_tup` in `pg_stat_all_tables` is the perfect way to monitor that, because that is the value that triggers autovacuum.

From v13 on, you also have to watch `n_ins_since_vacuum`, because autovacuum is also triggered by inserts there.

Normally, there is no reason to be afraid of anti-wraparound vacuum runs. PostgreSQL 9.6 introduced an optimization that allows such `VACUUM` runs to skip pages with only frozen tuples.

The exception might be a table that receives almost only inserts. You could potentially get massive anti-wraparound `VACUUM` runs there. A way to avoid that is to drastically lower `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` for such tables, so that you get anti-wraparound `VACUUM` runs there earlier and more often. This problem has been abolished with PostgreSQL v13.